# Como alterar a cor azul /vermelho de um campo editado

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Possuo a seguinte tela :

https://snag.gy/wmPBpM.jpg

Como posso alterar o campo, da lista, previsao1 de forma que fique vermelho ou azul conforme edito ele e salvo alterando seu valor.

Segue o xhtml.

```
<p:dataTable id="produtosTable"
                value="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.lazyModel}" var="produto"
                style="margin-top: 20px" emptyMessage="Nenhuma Previsão Encontrada"
                paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="5" paginator="true"
                paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink}"
                currentPageReportTemplate="(#{msg.pagina} {currentPage} #{msg.de} {totalPages}) - (#{msg.registro} {startRecord} #{msg.a} {endRecord}) - Total ({totalRecords} #{msg.registros})"
                styleClass="mystyle" paginatorAlwaysVisible="true"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="10, 20, 30" lazy="true">

                <f:facet id="header" name="header">
               Previsão de Vendas
            </f:facet>


                <p:column headerText=" Codigo do Produto"
                    sortBy="#{produto.codigoProduto}"
                    style="text-align: center; width: 140px">

                    <p:commandLink value="#{produto.codigoProduto}"
                        update=":userDetailForm:display" oncomplete="userDialog.show()"
                        title="View">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{produto}"
                            target="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.previsaoSelecionada}" />
                    </p:commandLink>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText=" Descrição"
                    style="text-align: center; width: 140px">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{produto.descricao}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{produto.descricao}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>




                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText=" Filial"
                    style="text-align: center; width: 140px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{produto.codigoFilial}">

                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText=" Custo Unitário"
                    style="text-align: center; width: 140px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{produto.valor}">

                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>


                <p:column headerText=" Fator de Alisamento"
                    style="text-align: center; width: 140px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{produto.fatorAmortecimentoExponencial}">

                    </h:outputText>


                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText=" Previsão1"
                    style="text-align: center; width: 140px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{produto.quantidadeRecente}">

                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText=" Previsão2"
                    style="text-align: center; width: 140px">

                    <h:outputText value="#{produto.quantidadeRecente}">

                    </h:outputText>

                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText=" Previsão3"
                    style="text-align: center; width: 140px">

                    <h:outputText value="#{produto.quantidadeRecente}">

                    </h:outputText>

                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText=" Receita da Previsão"
                    style="text-align: center; width: 140px">

                    <h:outputText value="#{produto.quantidadeReais}">
                        <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2"
                            maxFractionDigits="2" />
                    </h:outputText>

                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width: 100px; text-align: center"
                    headerText="#{msg.acoes}">

                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" title="#{msg.excluir}"
                        oncomplete="confirmacaoExclusao.show()" process="@this"
                        update=":frmPesquisa:confirmacaoExclusaoDialog">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener
                            target="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.previsaoSelecionada}"
                            value="#{previsao}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>

            <p:confirmDialog header="#{msg.exclui_tecnico}"
                widgetVar="confirmacaoExclusao" id="confirmacaoExclusaoDialog">
                <p:button value="#{msg.nao}"
                    onclick="confirmacaoExclusao.hide(); return false;" />
                <p:commandButton value="#{msg.sim}"
                    oncomplete="confirmacaoExclusao.hide();"
                    action="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.excluir}" process="@this"
                    update=":frmPesquisa:produtosTable" />
            </p:confirmDialog>

        </h:form>
        <p:dialog header="Alterar Previsão" widgetVar="userDialog"
            resizable="false" id="userDlg">
            <h:form id="userDetailForm">
                <p:panelGrid id="display" columns="4" cellpadding="4"
                    style="margin:0 auto;">


                    <p:outputLabel value="Ultimo Ano:" for="ultimoAno" />
                    <p:inputText id="ultimoAno" disabled="true"
                        value="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.previsaoSelecionada.anoAnterior}" />

                    <p:outputLabel value="Quantidade:" for="quantidade" />
                    <p:inputText id="quantidade" disabled="true"
                        value="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.previsaoSelecionada.ultimaQuantidade}" />


                    <p:outputLabel value="terceiro Mês:" for="terceiroMes" />
                    <p:inputText id="terceiroMes" disabled="true"
                        value="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.previsaoSelecionada.terceiroMesAnterior}" />

                    <p:outputLabel value="Quantidade:" for="quantidade4" />
                    <p:inputText id="quantidade4" disabled="true"
                        value="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.previsaoSelecionada.terceiraQuantidade}" />


                    <p:outputLabel value="Penultimo Mês:" for="segundoMes" />
                    <p:inputText id="segundoMes" disabled="true"
                        value="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.previsaoSelecionada.segundoMesAnterior}" />

                    <p:outputLabel value="Quantidade:" for="quantidade3" />
                    <p:inputText id="quantidade3" disabled="true"
                        value="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.previsaoSelecionada.segundaQuantidade}" />


                    <p:outputLabel value="Ùltimo mês:" for="primeiroMes" />
                    <p:inputText id="primeiroMes" disabled="true"
                        value="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.previsaoSelecionada.primeiroMesAnterior}" />

                    <p:outputLabel value="Quantidade:" for="quantidade1" />
                    <p:inputText id="quantidade1" disabled="true"
                        value="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.previsaoSelecionada.primeiraQuantidade}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Previsao:"></h:outputText>

                    <h:inputText
                        value="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.previsaoSelecionada.quantidadeRecente}" />


                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:commandButton id="alterar" value="Alterar"
                            update=":frmPesquisa:produtosTable"
                            oncomplete="tratarAssociacao(args)"
                            actionListener="#{pesquisaPrevisaoBean.alterarPrevisao}" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

Será necessário colocar uma operador ternário no Previsão1. Algo semelhante a isso:

```
<h:outputText value="#{produto.quantidadeRecente} style="#{produto.estoqueInsuficiente ? 'color: red' : ''}">
```

Considere que o estoqueInsuficiente é um método que retorna uma boolean com o estoque do produto.

Tirei esse trecho de código daqui:
https://github.com/algaworks/curso-javaee-primefaces/blob/master/AtualizandoHibernate5/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/template/pedidos/ItensPedido.xhtml